# Apple Numbers: keyboard shortcut for "smart fill"?

Tags: iwork, iwork-numbers

If I've got some sort of patterned data selected — say sequential numbers — I can click and drag the little circle in the bottom right corner of that selection to “smart fill”. For example:

[image][image]

Is there a keyboard shortcut for doing this? Eg, so I can use shift+arrow keys to select the "1 2 3", then press "something" to extend it down to get the "4 5 6"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh then thats easy.  Go to System Preferences > Keyboard.  Click on the Keyboard Shortcuts tab.  Then select, "Application Shortcuts" in the left side selection pane.  Under the shortcuts list, click the small "+" sign to open the Add Shortcut dialog box.  Use the Application drop down menu to find Numbers, if you moved it or can't find it, select "Other" at the bottom and find it via the "Open Application" dialog box.  Type "Fill Down" as the "Menu Title," then click in the "Keyboard Shortcut" text box and enter your shortcut.

Then check back in Numbers in the Insert > Fill > Fill Down menu and look at your beautiful new shortcut.

but to answer your original question....no, there isn't one.  Since, there's no menu item for Smart Fill, its not possible to create one.  Even starting out with more than one cell selected only does a regular fill from the first cell in the selection group.

Cheers.

Answer (score -3):

I recently ran into this problem while using Numbers for some tedious css shortcuts.  If you select a single number and fill it down, it will fill with more of that number.  If you however, select 1 and 2 in the same column, then fill those two numbers down, it will continue counting.  The same is true for counting in multiples (like by 3s for example, or odds).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That is a useful tip, but unfortunately not at all relevant to this specific question (which is asking about keyboard shortcuts).

Comment: Agreed. Shame as you will earn vote ups on the accepted answer and vote downs on this answer. Consider deleting this or instead adding to your accepted answer? Or as a comment?